# Importing data from AWS Athena query resultant Data to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-athena, amazon-aurora

I have a set of AWS Athena queries that I am executing manually on my S3 folder. The next step would be to get the query result and push it to a Aurora MYSQL Database. The Athena table I have created by using AWS Glue.

Please find below my queries.

1. Is there any AWS Service that can help in querying using the Athena Query and insert resultant rows into RDS
2. if yes for query 1 then, Can that service be scheduled.

Presently I have created a lambda for this operation

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083992/importing-data-from-aws-athena-to-rds-instance)

Comment: You seem to be using lambda already, is that not working as you expect? You can schedule a lambda to run the first query, write the results in the output bucket, and trigger the second lambda that will insert in mysql once those results appear in the bucket.